# How to get scrollviewer to scroll to selected item work properly c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive-design, scrollview, tablet

I am writing a wpf application that will be used on a surface. Sometimes when the touch keyboard comes up, it covers fields that the user needs to enter. I am trying to put a scrollviewer on the page that will scroll to different textboxes when they are selected. My app only has about 8 fields on a given page, and is almost never larger than the screen (so it never really needs to actually use a scroll). I'm not sure if that's relevant. right now, I have the following method:

```
private void OnFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!MyScrollViewer.IsEnabled)
        {
           MyScrollViewer.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        MyScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
        MyScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset -100);
    }
```

Please not that this is not the actual code that I want to use, I'm just trying to play around with the scrollviewer to see something happen on the screen so I can gauge how to use it. Currenlty nothing happens on the screen. If anyone could offer any insight as to how this works and what I am doing wrong, that would be great. 
thanks for looking!

Comment: And what kind of WPF control resides in that ScrollViewer? Best regards,

Comment: The scrollviewer is on a page, the page has textboxes, a date time picker and buttons.

Comment: Then why do you need additional ScrollView if you can use the one in TextBox, which seems the only control which can grow with User text entry? Use something like: <TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

Comment: I'm not sure I follow 100%. Will this make the screen shot the textbox if it is covered by the on screen keyboard? I was under the impression that I needed to manually set the page's scrollviewer to get to the correct offset to show the text box that is being typed in.

Comment: I guess you are talking about touch-screen implementation? Or a regular desktop app with your own on-screen virtual keypad added?

Comment: That is correct, I'm working with a touch screen implementation.

Comment: Then the on-screen keyboard may cover other controls, but in the TextBox control you may use its vertical scrollbar to get to the caret for data entry. It's still a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve, in particular, what is the "selected item" pertinent to TextBox?

Comment: When I select textboxes at the bottom of the app to type in, the on screen keyboard that I need to use covers the field that I am trying to type in. I would like my application to scroll to that textbox so the user can see what they are typing into the textbox. I hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the size of that on-screen virtual keyboard (which, I guess, may vary depends on the PC platform), then you can position the TextBox above that keyboard; no need for the scroll bar in this case.

Comment: Not exactly grab your idea, but how about `ScrollIntoView`? Not a method of `ScrollViewer` itself, but some controls have.